# Vertica query explicitly showing records that do not exist

Tags: sql, vertica

I know it sounds weird, but I'm looking for a way to force Vertica to show an indicator when a record do not actually exist - probably it's easier to understand using an example.

Let's imagine that I want to look for the existence of 3 records in a table, each one with a unique job_id key: `(100,200,300)` , and I want to get some other fields for the same record, like a timestamp or whatever...

I'd do something like this:

```
vsql> select job_id, date from my_table where job_id in (100,200,300);
```

If there are only records for `100` and `300`, the result should be something like:

```
 job_id |     date
--------+---------
    100 | 01/01/01
    300 | 03/03/03
```

What I would like to get as a result is:

```
 job_id |     date
--------+---------
    100 | 01/01/01
    200 | 
    300 | 03/03/03
```

Why?  Because I want to append data from other sources into the query's output, and this source take into account all job_ids, even if there are no records for it in my_table.

I know you can `JOIN` a table with itself, but that didn't work in this case because neither of the tables (the same, d'oh) have the missing record in them.  Therefore, this problem looks like something that is prevented *by design*, but I wonder if someone else had the same need.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you going to store the `job_id`s that don't exist in your left set? I would populate them in table and join to them, or for a small number of jobs, use lad2025's answer below.

Comment: Are your job_id values predictable?  Do they always go up in increments of 100?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` and subquery:

```
SELECT sub.job_id,
       m.date, 
       CASE WHEN m.job_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS indicator
FROM (SELECT 100 AS job_id
      UNION ALL SELECT 200 
      UNION ALL SELECT 300) AS sub
LEFT JOIN my_table m
  ON sub.job_id = m.job_id;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/407652)**</kbd>

I don't know `Vertica` but in `SQL Sever` you can change subquery  with:

- `VALUES`
- select from temporary table
- select from table variable/table valued parameter